# How to cast an object to a class by its name

Tags: java, casting

I have an Object which is actually String Long or Integer.
I want to cast it to the right Class, which I know by parameter and then compare the values.
Right now I'm doing:

```
switch(type) {
case Float:
    (Float) obj ...
    ....
case Long:
    (Long) obj ...
    ...
case String:
    (String) obj ...
    ....
}
```

in each case the rest of the code is the same except casting a few objects to the specific class chosen.

I'm wondering if there is any better way to do it, so I tried the following:

```
Integer myInteger = 100;
Object myObject = myInteger;

Class c = java.lang.Integer.class;  
Integer num1 = java.lang.Integer.class.cast(myObject); // works
Integer num2 = c.cast(myObject); // doesn't compile
Integer num3 = (java.lang.Integer) myObject; // works
```

the compilation error I get:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer

I would like to know why it happens, also a solution for my code duplication

Comment: this is not clear. you want to detect the type of your variable automatically avoiding a second parameter?

Comment: no, @m0skit0 answered my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Class<Integer>` so compiler is aware of which class you're referring to

```
Class<Integer> c = java.lang.Integer.class;
Integer num2 = c.cast(myObject); // works now
```

On a side note, this kind of unsafe casting is highly not recommended. If you can change your logic to something that does not require passing an Object and casting (like generics for example), then it's better. If not, I suggest that at least you to make sure the Object is of that type before casting using `instanceof` (as shown in [kocko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31582292/898478)).

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I'm storing a map of (string,Object), and the Object could be a few things. after that I send this object to a class which uploads it to a key value database.
Do you have any suggestion to make it different with more logic?

Comment: My question is, why use Map<String, Object>? Are you sure you can't store it in another way? A DB for example? What kind of objects are you storing? If only "simple" objects (only strings and numbers, no lists, or complicated objects) maybe it's better to use Map<String, String> and parse when required instead of casting.

Comment: it is only string and numbers, but I thought it will be more efficient to cast.
Casting just tells it what is the object type, while for parsing I need to go over the object. am I correct?

Comment: Yeah right. Forget my previous suggestion about Map<String, String>, I think it's not a better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (obj instanceof Float) {
    Float cast = (Float) obj;
} else if (obj instanceof String) {
    String cast = (String) obj;
} else if ..
```

This will make your code work, however if I were you, I would think about some refactoring, as this breaks the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Comment: You're right, but I don't think this is what is being asked.